# Can't avoid one side of a div sticking to another div

Tags: html

I'm trying to put two divs on a form. Whatever I try I can't prevent one side of the second div from sticking to the other one. I need them to stay side by side, so I've set the first div to float:left. I give a bold blue border to the second div and one of the borders which is adjacent to the first div is invisible.

```
<div class=div-first>
    <div>
        <table >
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Caller No</th>
                    <th scope="col">Call date</th>
                    <th scope="col">Call time</th>
                    <th scope="col">Answer mode</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>519202976</td>
                    <td>2013-11-13</td>
                    <td>16:03:28</td>
                    <td>Manual</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>125108094</td>
                    <td>2013-11-13</td>
                    <td>16:02:59</td>
                    <td>Manual</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="div-second" >
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Call date</td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtCallDate"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    .div-second{border:20px solid #0094ff;margin:30px;}

    .div-first{float: left; border:5px solid black}
```

[Here's the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MikeJM/9A9s5/). Any ideas why?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9A9s5/1/

Comment: Sorry,@abhitalks, I'd forgotten to update the fiddle.

Comment: What I meant to convey thru that fiddle was that you need proper widths on `div-first` and the table inside that. Otherwise your `float` will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to float both divs.

```
.div-second{float:left; border:20px solid #0094ff;margin:30px;}
```

will move your second div away from the first.

Press ctrl+shift+c in Chrome and move the mouse over the blue border. It will show you what actually happened to the second div; It gets stretched down all the way from your first div.

Comment: Thanks, @Chris, it did really work. I hadn't tried that because I've many times done the same thing without having divs overlapping each other.